# Incorrect value for combination in R

Tags: r, combinations

Using the `combinat` package in R, I get an incorrect answer for

```
dim(combn(9,9))[2]
```

I get `NULL` instead of `1`

Am I using the package incorrectly ? Or is there a different package out there to solve this ?

Comment: Technically, I think it is behaving as documented, i.e. "If simplify is FALSE, returns a list; else returns a vector or an array.". But I mostly agree that I would prefer a more consistent return value, if it were me.

Comment: ...the implication being that if you want a reasonably consistent structure for the returned object from `combinat::combn` then you should probably use `simplify = FALSE`.

Comment: @markus, this is the code using combinat, I called the package earlier, and then used combn to get my answer

Comment: I am sorry, thought you were using `utils::combn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Am I using the package incorrectly ?"

No, you are not using the package incorrectly. As @joran points out, from the documentation for the `simplify` argument for `combinat::combn` (which has a default value of `TRUE`), this behavior is expected:

> If simplify is FALSE, returns a list; else returns a vector or an array.

So, in your example, since `combinat::combn(9, 9)` has only one result, a vector is returned, which doesn't have attributes like a matrix (e.g. `dim`) .

"Or is there a different package out there to solve this ?"

Yes, simply using the `utils` package that comes as one of the standard libraries with `R` fixes this issue (same as `combinat`, the default value for `simplify` is `TRUE`):

```
## with utils
dim(utils::combn(9,9))[2]
[1] 1
```

Again, from the docs for `utils::combn` we have (emphasis mine):

> Scott Chasalow wrote the original in 1994 for S; R package combinat and documentation by Vince Carey stvjc@channing.harvard.edu; small changes by the R core team, notably to return an **ARRAY** in all cases of simplify = TRUE, e.g., for combn(5,5).

Note that it says **array** (an array in `R` is a vector with additional attributes.. furthermore a two-dimensional array is simply a matrix) and does not mention a vector as they did with `combinat`.

And for thoroughness, here is what `utils::combn` says for the argument `simplify`:

> logical indicating if the result should be simplified to an array (typically a matrix); if FALSE, the function returns a list. Note that when simplify = TRUE as by default, the dimension of the result is simply determined from FUN(1st combination) (for efficiency reasons). This will badly fail if FUN(u) is not of constant length.

Since we have only 1 combination from `utils::combn(9, 9)`, we obtain an array (i.e. a matrix) with 1 column and 9 rows, so calling `dim()[2]` returns 1 as expected.